# Images in gridview fetched from database are not showing in fullscreen upon Clicking by using onItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, gridview

I am using `GridView` for Displaying my images from mysql Databse.
But, when I try to display the images in FullScreen upon clicking using `OnItemClickListener` the app does not crash, however it does not display my UI.

here is the code for MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
// Log tag
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://eventassociate.com/wedding/photomania";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();

private GridView gridView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
Button blackcapture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallary_activity_main);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    blackcapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottom_button);
    blackcapture.setOnClickListener(this);

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);




    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            Movie m5 = movieList.get(position);

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    FullImageActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("movieobject", m5);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });











    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("No"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("flinks"));

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });
```

Code for CustomAdapter:-

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    private Activity activity;

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}







@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallary_list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);








    // ...............................................

    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());







    return convertView;

}
```

Code for Movie Class:-

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable{
private String title,thumbnailUrl;



public Movie() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Movie(String name, String thumbnailUrl
        ) {
    this.title = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;

}



public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = "http://eventassociate.com/wedding/"+thumbnailUrl;
}

 // Parcelling part
public Movie(Parcel in){
    String[] data = new String[2];

    in.readStringArray(data);
    this.title = data[0];
    this.thumbnailUrl = data[1];

}








@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.title,
                                        this.thumbnailUrl,
                                        });
}
```

}

And Code for FullImageActivity:-

public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

 // get intent data



    Intent i = getIntent();

    Movie myParcelableObject = (Movie) i.getParcelableExtra("movieobject");



   String alp =  myParcelableObject.getThumbnailUrl();


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), alp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);







}
```

}

Comment: Shows the crash report??

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow. It is customary when asking how to fix an Exception (crash) that you provide the full stack trace in your question. Otherwise it cannot be diagnosed. That is typically found in the logcat for Android. Please [edit] your question to provide this log.

Comment: @Knossos Thanks,but the app doesnt crashes.When FullImageActivity is called only blank screen shows.

Comment: Then this text is wrong and confusing `the app crashes`. I will edit that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your `FullImageActivity`

1. You are initializing `CustomListAdapter` int the `FullImageActivity` why? It is not required here.
2. You got the position from the previous activity. It is better to get the id of the image from the bundle.

If you get the id from the bundle then hit the database and get the image based on the id and assign the image to imageview.

Comment: Thanks. But, i have a confusion.If i pass id from MainActivity to FullImageActivity using Bundle , basically what does id contain & how  can i use it to fetch image from database.

Comment: In your question you mentioned like "I am using GridView for Displaying my images from mysql Databse". So I thought your database contains Images/image location info. So from id you passed in bundle you can get the image from database.

Comment: there is no problem in displaying images from database in gridview.The problem is to show them in full screen by clicking on them.Hope u can help.

Comment: How you getting images from database to show in gridview?

Comment: Using JSON parsing. I am editing the question and including the complete code for MainActivity.java.  You can check that out.

Comment: My main doubt is how to use position parameter to access "getthumbnailUrl" method of Movie class.

Comment: You have movieList in "MainActivity". First parcelize the Movie object. When you click on grid item get the Moive object form the movie list and send it throw the bundle and in "FullImageActivity" get the Movie object and call moive.getThumbnailUrl() method.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience .But ,still have doubt. When i click on Griditem , how to get the Movie object from the movie list and what is the use of position parameter then.

Comment: Where you written your onItemClick listener if it is in MainActivity then in onItemClick() method you will get position parameter. With that position you can get Movie object by movieList.get(position) or you will get AdapterView object then by using it you will get Movie object by adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: I have made changes as you have told.Please, have a look at my code(i'have updated the question with updated code).But,now the app crashes when MainActivity is called.Looking forwrd for your help.

Comment: What exception you are getting and where you getting?

Comment: i have sorted nullpointer exception.But,after making all the changes u told,when i run the app the app crashes with BadParceableException at fullimageactivity.

Comment: You are not implemented parcellable correctly...check some examples in google for parcellable...

Comment: Thank u very very much for your help.It finally worked.